# vim: found /var/log or similar

Tags: vim

On vim for search an exact word i type

```
/\<port\>
```

in this case it return every occurence of port
,how to found /var/adm or /var/log entries?
I have tried

```
/\<\/var/\adm/>
```

but no success,it cut on var
Thanks

Comment: Escape the foward slashes...

Comment: : \<\/var\/adm\>          
This doesn't work,i have escaped forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\/var\/adm\>`

`\<` means start of a word (/var is not start of a word)